# How to combine Promises with if?

Tags: javascript, promise

In the following example, I would like to conditionally execute `somePromise`, then regardless of the condition execute `anotherPromise`.

```
if (somecondition) {
    somePromise().then((args) => { ... } );
}

// Not waiting for somePromise() here, but it should.
return anotherPromise().then((args) => {
    muchmorecodehere;
}
```

The only way I can think of right now is to turn the last part into a function and execute it in both branches, but that seems very cumbersome. Surely I'm doing something wrong?

```
let helperFunction = () => {
    return anotherPromise().then((args) => {
        muchmorecodehere;
    }
}

if (somecondition) {
    return somePromise().then((args) => { ... } ).then(helperFunction);
}

return helperFunction;
```

Comment: Just to clarify - if `somePromise` executes, do you want `anotherPromise` to wait for that to finish before starting? Or do you just want them both to run?

Comment: Why not to use chain and reject by some condition first to avoid executing second?

Comment: Yes, `anotherPromise` should wait for `somePromise` to finish first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `.then()` returns a new promise and chain off either that or a dummy promise:

```
var nextPromise = somecondition
    ? somePromise.then((args) => { ... })
    : Promise.resolve();

return nextPromise.then(() => anotherPromise)
    .then((args) => {
        // muchmorecodehere
    });
```

Comment: If I understand your solution correctly, `somePromise` is executed regardless of the condition. I'd like to execute `somePromise` only if the condition is true. Maybe instead of `: somePromise`, `: Promise.resolve()` or something along those lines?

Comment: @cib You can replace the `somePromise` on line 3 with `Promise.resolve()` and I've edited my post to do so, but it seems you might have some confusion about how promises work. They usually don't wait to execute until you call `.then()` on them. They usually begin executing as soon as you create them. `then()` just provides a way to get at the result when it's available.

Comment: Fair point, I should probably have written `somePromise` as `createSomePromise()` instead, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a default, already resolved, promise (lets call it `conditionalPromise`), for the conditional part and always chain this promise with `anotherPromise`.

If `someCondition` is `false` then `conditionalPromise` is an already resolved promise and it can be safely chained to `anotherPromise`.

If `someCondition` is `true` then `somePromise` is assigned to `conditionalPromise` and when it will be resolved, then `anotherPromise` will be executed.

```
conditionalPromise = Promise.resolve(); // Create a default, already resolved, promise
if (someCondition) {
    // Assign somePromise to conditionalPromise, overwriting the default one
    conditionalPromise = somePromise
}

// Now chain the 2 promises
return conditionalPromise.then((args) => { 
    anotherPromise.then((args) => {
        muchmorecodehere;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get around the problem, is to just wrap the initial `if` in a `then` block by chaining it to a `Promise.resolve()`.

```
return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    if (somecondition) {
        return somePromise().then((args) => { ... } );
    }
}).then(() => {
    return anotherPromise();
}).then((args) => {
    //muchmorecodehere
});
```